# Update failed after edit the data [no error]

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I have made a edit form...but when i press the edit button..it works...when after complete the edit if i press the update button...it goes to main page but no field updated.

**edit.page**

```
<body>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">Edit data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="2">
<th>SL</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>action</th>
<?php
include"dbc.php";//database conncetion
$order = "select * from tbl_record";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$order);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo ("<tr><td>$row[employees_number]</td>");
echo ("<td>$row[name]</td>");
echo ("<td>$row[address]</td>");
echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[employees_number]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

edit form

```
<body>
<table border=2>
  <tr>
    <td align=center>Form Edit Employees Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
      <?php
      include "dbc.php";//database connection
      $id = $_GET["id"];
      $order = "SELECT * FROM tbl_record where employees_number='$id'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$order);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "$row[employees_number]"?>">
        <tr>        
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" 
        size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[name]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="address" size="40" 
          value="<?php echo "$row[address]"?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            <input type="submit" 
          name="submit value" value="Edit">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**update page**

```
<?php
//edit_data.php
include "dbc.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$address = $_POST["address"];

mysqli_query("UPDATE tbl_record SET name='$name', address='$address' WHERE employees_number='$id'")
 or die(mysqli_error()); 
}
header("location:edit.php");
?>
```

Comment: `name="submit value"` remove the space and the word "value". `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">` <= change to that. If that fixes is, which I am pretty sure it will, just delete your question. Typo questions are considered off-topic on Stack.

Comment: @Fred-ii-...thank you for your comment...still result same

Comment: You're welcome. Can you edit your code to reflect that change? We can then delete these comments and make way for any others that may spot anything else.

Comment: if you have teamviewer you can help me

Comment: I don't know what that is, therefore I probably don't have it ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-..ok...i am getting this error now mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given ...for update page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68567/discussion-between-sazal-ahmed-and-fred-ii).

Comment: I have posted an answer for you below in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment *"i am getting this error now mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given ...for update page"*

Add your connection parameter to the query:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE
```

to that it reads as

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ...
```

Plus, your submit button should read as:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
```

The `name="submit value"` in it now, doesn't match the conditional statement for it
`if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: it is not update the address field..but update the name field to 0

Comment: @SazalAhmed Can you `var_dump()` and see what's passing through or not?

Comment: @fred...i cannot recognize it how i will do that

Comment: @SazalAhmed When you're in `edit form`, does anything appear in the HTML source of both fields in "value"?

Comment: @fred...yes ...values are showing in edit form...but after editing when press the button...it goes to main page ...there the name value show 0 and address field value donot update